# Get values through post method from URL

Tags: php, mysql, json, post

I am trying some code to get value from URL through post method and search database table for that value and get info from the database and encode it into JSON response.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
if (isset($_POST['empid'])) {
    $k = $_POST['empid'];
    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select `salary` from tbl_employee where `employee_id` = $k ";
} else {
    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select `salary` from tbl_employee";
}
//fetch table rows from mysql db
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

I used Postman extension on Chrome and pass the values but it is not returning. Instead it is returning the else part.

Postman Screenshot
[image]

Comment: do u have form for this value `empid`?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`  If the value you are looking for is not there, then postman isn't working

Comment: Can you provide more details about how and what you passs in your postman

Comment: @mukund Selected POST from dropdown,added the local url,clicked on params and gave key as empid and value as 1.

Comment: If your else code executes that means the $_POST['empid'] wasnt sent, because it is not set

Comment: Are you using "form-data" or "URL params" for defining POST parameter?

Comment: @Tamil No I am using postman extension in chrome

Comment: I'm using that too. That why i asked how you defined your post parameter. There will two options 1. Using URL Params and another one is body->form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded or raw or binary.  If you are using latest version, then there will be a option called "Generate Code". Share it for debug

Comment: Are you sure you have selected body tab and added key as empid and value for it?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your postman?

Comment: @mukund hi added screenshot

Comment: you need to dump or print_r $_POST

Comment: how ? can you show me an example

Comment: try to import this into Postman ( Import->paste as raw text)

`curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: db84566f-9d15-376e-65f5-38636020c716" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'empid=2' "https://httpbin.org/post"`

It calls an echo service. You can see the response includes the empid POST variable

`... "form": {
    "empid": "2"
  }, ...`

as @mukund mentioned, your "POST" should not be defined in the query string (thos are GET variables)

Comment: Your code is wide open to "SQL Injection".  You have neither quoted, nor escaped, `$k` in the SQL statement.

Comment: Let's see the html "Source".  It is not obvious whether you need `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, i created the database and reproduced your code localy and it's running well, probably it's a problem with postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your screenshot you are sending your `empid` through query parameter so you need to access that as follows

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['empid'])) {
    echo $_GET['empid'];
}else{
    // else part
}
```

also for that you need to Request Url in Postman using `GET` method.

But as you have stated that you want to send `empid` through `POST` in postman, you have to send it through `form-data` in Postman and access it as `$_POST["empid"];`. following is the screenshot for your reference
[image]

else there is another option where you can send the `POST` data through `body` as `row json` and access it as

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonData = json_decode($rawPostData);
```

and `$post` will contain the `raw data`. And you can send it through postman as in following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @Melvin did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your screen shot, you have not passed body key values, instead you passed params.

[image]
Click on Body Tab and then pass key & value pair.

Comment: Try to check with <?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
Are you actually receiving any data or not

Comment: i am getting the else condition

Comment: I mean what you received in postdata as per above, because setting shown in screenshot are enough to receive post data - 
Body - key value - select form data

Comment: I am getting all data as result when i tried your solution

Comment: You mean you received expected data in that as string?

Comment: no i did not get . I got all the data instead which i used in else part

Comment: Are you getting the result ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the  Body to "x-www-form-urlencoded" and adding the variables to be posted

[image]

Or try this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173721/can-not-send-post-variables-to-php-script-on-localhost-using-postman), its already been answered

Answer (score 1):

I replicated the code and db on my system to figure out the problem. I also added some lines of code before `if (isset($_POST['empid'])) {` for diagnostics sake:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
echo $method."<br/>";
```

The application file is `index.php` deployed in `json` directory inside webroot.

When I send any request to http://localhost/json directory (either POST/GET), Apache redirects the request as a GET request to index.php (as configured in my Apache config file). I assume this is what you're experiencing.

But when I send the request to http://localhost/json/index.php, the request is accurately received and processed.

Therefore, I would say the solution is that you need to specify the `php` file and also set the `empid` parameter as part of the body in Postman (not as part of the url).

[image]

[image]

Comment: but you do not forget SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also check the post if empty`if (isset($_POST['empid']) AND ($_POST['empid']) != "")`. to allow php to execute the line before `else.`Sometimes programming becomes unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

use `if(isset($_REQUEST['empid']))` to test in POSTMAN...

Then use `if(isset($_POST['empid']))` to test directly from app...

have a look Issue in POSTMAN https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/391

Answer (score 0):

**Submitting a form through POST method**

By post method of form submission, we can send number or length of data. Sensitive information like password does not get exposed in URL by POST method, so our login forms we should use POST method to submit data. This is how we collect data submitted by POST method in PHP

`$id=$_POST['id'];`

`$password=$_POST['password'];`

**Collecting data submitted by either GET or POST method**

If a page is receiving a data which can come in any one of the method GET or POST then how to collect it ? Here we are not sure how to collect the data. So we will use like this.

`$id=$_REQUEST['id'];`

`$password=$_REQUEST['password'];`

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a variable from the **`URL(query string)`**, you need to use either `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.`$_POST` represents data that is sent to the script via the `HTTP POST method`.

So, in your code you just need to do this :

`$_REQUEST['empid']` instead of `$_POST['empid']`

In **`POST`** method the data is sent to the server as a package in a separate communication with the processing script. Data sent through **`POST`** method will not visible in the URL.

Confirm that in postman `Content-Type` should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in request header.

**Postman reference doc :** https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Answer (score 0):

Hey it sounds like you are just needing to do a GET request to your DB.

You are more than welcome to send in variables via a GET request as well.

GET    http://localhost/json?empid=3

You can then get data from your GET request like so `$_GET['empid']`

I suggest a GET request because I see your not actually posting any data to your server, your just handing in a variable in which you want to use to query with.

I do understand that GET requests are less secure, but in your scenario your POST just doesn't seem to want to work. So a different tack might do you justice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value from the URL, you need to use `$_GET["empid"]` instead `$_POST["empid"]`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL you are requesting, you are sending a `GET` value within your `POST` request.

```
http://localhost/json?empid=3
```

As you can see here, the url holds the empid variable and so the is send to the server as beeing a GET variable ($_GET)

Use `$_GET['empid']` to access this variable, while using $_POST to access the other variables.

You could also use `$_REQUEST` to access both `GET` and `POST` data by the same global.